# Can I configure one MvcSiteMapProvider node for multiple actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSiteMapProvider only for displaying BreadCrumb on my side. I am having multiple masters (specifically, 27) in my application with CRUD screens. Each master has a controller, with Index, Create, Edit, Detail and Delete action. 
I don't want in detail breadcrumb for each action, only controller is enough for me. 
E.g
1. Organisation Setup:
    - Department Group
        * Department
    - Project Group
        * Project
    - etc Groups

Now, when I configure MvcSiteMapProvider xml sitemap, i need something like this

```xml
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Department Group" controller="DeptGrp" action="*"> 
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Department" controller="department" action="*" /> 
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Project Group" controller="PrjGrp" action="*"> 
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Project" controller="project" action="*" /> 
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But, MvcSiteMapProvider does allow action name to "*". It needs to be specific. How do I configure map just base on controller, when action does have play any significance in node selection, in sitemaphelper to display breadcrumb?

I use this to display breadcrumb

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to match more than one action with a single node.

The idea is that you need to create a hierarchy in the `MvcSiteMapProvider` configuration for navigation because MVC doesn't automatically provide one. Note that you can use [visibility providers](https://github.com/maartenba/mvcsitemapprovider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider) to hide any nodes that you don't want shown in the `SiteMapPath`.

If you have a specific convention you are following, you could use either a [dynamic node provider](https://github.com/maartenba/mvcsitemapprovider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) or implement `ISiteMapNodeProvider` and use `Reflection` to discover your actions so there is a node added for each one automatically.

Another option is to use a single action on each controller with a parameter. In that case, you can use `preservedRouteParameters` to [force a match](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match) on every value for that parameter and then you will only need a single node for the entire controller.

But whatever the case, you need a node for each action.